# The triggered notifications are not receiving in to the android devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

The triggered notifications are not receiving in to the android devices, and these scenario's are failing to receive the notification.

1) When the Android/iOS mobile app doesn't has the internet but notifications are triggered from the FCM Console or FCM Api(We developed the api to trigger notifications). Few minutes later Android/iOS mobile app get internet access, immediately Android/iOS mobile app should get all triggered notifications. But Android mobile app doesn't receive the any notifications, iOS mobile app able to receive the all notifications.

2) We have Scheduler to schedule the notifications by Daily basis, the android mobile app is not receiving the scheduled notifications from the FCM Server, but iOS mobile app received all scheduled notifications from the FCM Server.

Kindly requesting you please help me to resolve these scenario.

Let me know if you require more information on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are managed by firebase service for Android. Google software decides how to queue and when to push notifications to the device. If you are pushing iOS notifications through firebase, Apple service decides when to push notifications to the device. That means that these services doesn't have to follow the same pattern. The real question is if all notifications are received finally by android device or not. If all there is no error in your code. What you can do is to set higher priority for android notifications. Google service takes in count traffic, battery state and several other factors when sending notifications to device. If Android device does not receive any notifications during lets say 1 hr, you should revisit your code.